# How to make a TextField visible when a button is clicked in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, visible

I'm trying to create a GUI program which provides a user with a button.  When this button is clicked, it displays a textField and prompts user to enter a regular expression.

Here are the steps I've taken so far to implement this:

1. Created a JFrame and added a button, label and text field.
2. Set the text field visibility to "false" initially. Label and button
       visibility are set to "true"
3. Implemented the ActionListener interface and overrode the ActionPerformed method to change the textField visibility to "true" when the button is clicked.
4. Registered the ActionListener instance to the button.

When I run it this way, the text field does NOT become visible after clicking the button (it compiles fine, but nothing happens in the GUI)

However, if I change the label visibility to "false" initially, then add an action to set to "true" in the ActionListener, it works and BOTH the label and the textfield become visible on clicking the button.

What I want to know is why the textfield only becomes visible when there is a label included in the ActionListener?

In other words, why does this code NOT work?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RegularExpressionGui extends JFrame {

  private final JLabel label1; //label
  private final JTextField textField1;
  private JTextField textField2; //text field
  private final JButton button1; //button
  private final JTextArea textArea1; //textArea

  public RegularExpressionGui() {

      super("Regular Expression Lookup");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //GUI Layout

      //add the components

      label1 = new JLabel("Regular Expression");
      label1.setVisible(true);
      add(label1);

      textField1 = new JTextField("Enter Regular Expression here");
      textField1.setVisible(false);
      add(textField1);

      button1 = new JButton("Lookup Expression");
      add(button1);

      textArea1 = new JTextArea("Results");
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea1)); //makes the output area scrollable

      LookupHandler lookup = new LookupHandler();
      button1.addActionListener(lookup);
      textField1.addActionListener(lookup);

    } //end constructor 

  //inner class containing ActionListner 
  private class LookupHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

         if (event.getSource() == button1) {
          textField1.setVisible(true);

         }
       } 
  }

}
```

And why does this one work instead?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RegularExpressionGui extends JFrame {

  private final JLabel label1; //label
  private final JTextField textField1;
  private JTextField textField2; //text field
  private final JButton button1; //button
  private final JTextArea textArea1; //textArea

  public RegularExpressionGui() {

      super("Regular Expression Lookup");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //GUI Layout

      //add the components

      label1 = new JLabel("Regular Expression");
      label1.setVisible(false);
      add(label1);

      textField1 = new JTextField("Enter Regular Expression here");
      textField1.setVisible(false);
      add(textField1);

      button1 = new JButton("Lookup Expression");
      add(button1);

      textArea1 = new JTextArea("Results");
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea1)); //makes the output area scrollable

      LookupHandler lookup = new LookupHandler();
      button1.addActionListener(lookup);
      textField1.addActionListener(lookup);

    } //end constructor 

  //inner class containing ActionListner 
  private class LookupHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

               if (event.getSource() == button1) {
          textField1.setVisible(true);
          label1.setVisible(true);
         }
       } 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you don't need the inner class.

For your problem, if you remove the inner class and instead you implement `ActionListener` on your `RegularExpressionGui` class, then add `pack()` inside the `actionPerformed` it should work, because `pack()` should be calling to the `repaint` method. If you call your 1st code, and resize the window, you should now see it, because while resizing it, the Layout Manager is calling the repaint method.

So, your class should look like this one right now:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RegularExpressionGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  private final JLabel label1; //label
  private final JTextField textField1;
  private JTextField textField2; //text field
  private final JButton button1; //button
  private final JTextArea textArea1; //textArea

  public RegularExpressionGui() {

      super("Regular Expression Lookup");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //GUI Layout

      //add the components

      label1 = new JLabel("Regular Expression");
      label1.setVisible(true);
      add(label1);

      textField1 = new JTextField("Enter Regular Expression here");
      textField1.setVisible(false);
      add(textField1);

      button1 = new JButton("Lookup Expression");
      add(button1);

      textArea1 = new JTextArea("Results");
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea1)); //makes the output area scrollable

      //LookupHandler lookup = new LookupHandler();
      button1.addActionListener(this);
      textField1.addActionListener(this);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } //end constructor 

  //inner class containing ActionListner 
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
       if (event.getSource() == button1) {
        textField1.setVisible(true);
        //label1.setVisible(true);
        pack();
       }
     } 
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    new RegularExpressionGui();
  }
}
```